# New US visa approved while on travel

Tags: visas, h1b-visas

I currently have a H1-B visa which is due to expire in March 2022. My H1-B extension was submitted in June and is currently under review. I am in the US and will be travelling to the UK (sep 17) for a number of weeks on my current visa ( I am able to leave and re enter). What happens if my H1-B visa extension is approved while I am on travel? Should I return to the US before the start date of the extension? Or should I try to get a visa stamp for the extension while I am away? Will the H1-B extension begin from near the expiration date or will it start sooner?

Comment: you're probably going to get better answers on Expatriates https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/ because that's a long term working visa.

Comment: You write "I will soon be going on travel for a number of weeks on my current visa." This is unclear. What country are you in now? Where are you going? When are you going?

Comment: Edited to state country of origin and travel location

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has been asked on Expatriates, where I feel it belongs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not going to give you an answer as such, because any answer will be at best incomplete, and at worst, wrong.

Presumably your extension of status is being completed by your employer, or more likely your employers external immigration lawyers.  You NEED to talk to them about your travel plans.  For most visas, leaving the US with an extension of status request pending would result in that request being canceled.  H-1B is an exception to that rule, but if things are not done correctly it can still result in your extension request being canceled (eg, if the extension is filed whilst you are out of the country), or you status not being extended (eg, if you return to the US without providing details of the approved extension).

The ONLY party that can help you here is the lawyers who filed the extension. You should reach out to them (and/or your employer) immediately and discuss your travel plans with them.

Comment: Thanks, this is very good advice. I have looked into it more but will definitely be talking to my employer asap. I don't know why this didn't occur to me sooner.